# ajax post issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, youtube

I'm having an issue with posting data to my php script with ajax.

Firebug says:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   

com&enquiry=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com.au%0A%0AIt%20doesn't%20work..it's')

v2.js (line 1, col 60)
```

my JavaScripts are:

```
var g="name="+q.val()+"&phone="+k.val()+"&email="+l.val()+"&enquiry="+encodeURIComponent(i.val())


jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",url:"mail.php",data:g,cache:false,success:function(b){}})
```

enquiry is from a textarea and posted message is:

http://www.youtube.com.au

It doesn't work..it's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: { 
        name: q.val(),
        phone: k.val(),
        email: l.val(),
        enquiry: i.val()
    },
    cache: false,
    success:function(b) {

    }
});
```

This way jQuery will take care of properly url encoding all your parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the issue is I'm getting backslashes in php like `doesn\'t`. I was able to convert line breakers in to '<br>' like this: `enquiry: jQuery("#taEnquiry").val().split('\n').join('<br>')` Is this right? But how about backslashes?